# AWS multiple site-to-site VPN connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, vpn, amazon-vpc

I was reading through the docs about AWS VPN site-to-site connections and stumbled upon a limit of 10 connections per single VPC. I started wondering, what if I need to have hundreds or thousands connections between some premises and a single VPC? Failed to find any resource about it. Please help me understand, how this can be achieved.

**NOTE**: *Different* premises/sites to a *single* VPC.

Comment: Hundreds or thousands of *different sites* connecting to a single VPC?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot exactly, I'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: Noting that site-to-site VPN connections are ~$36/month each, don't support hairpinning, require static public IP addresses at each external site... I would speculate that this is not a desirable solution for hundreds or thousands of sites.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I see. How would you do that without site-to-site option of AWS VPC? Networking is not my strongest side, so I'd be happy if you could shed some light on how people usually achieve these types of goals.

Comment: What is the application? Multi-site retail? IoT? Site to site is commonly used for connecting data centers and corporate LAN to VPC, which would not typically involve such a large number of connections.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot For example, IoT. Let's say I have a VPC and thousands of locations with devices. I want these devices to communicate with ec2 instances in my VPC over VPN. I do understand that site-to-site or CloudHub solutions address different sort of problems. My question is how to achieve this type of topology on AWS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190591/discussion-between-vladyslav-usenko-and-michael-sqlbot).

Answer (score 0):

If you require more than 10 connections per single VPC, you need to raise a increase limit request with AWS support. Complete the Request to [Increase Amazon VPC Limits](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/cases#/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-vpc) form to request an increased limit.